# Build a Jenkins job on a merge request to master

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

In GitLab, whenever someone creates a Merge Request from some branch into master, I need that event to trigger a Jenkins job (Freestyle, yeah I know..) and pass the branch name as a parameter for the  Jenkins build.

I've looked and it seems like the closest thing to it is the `Jenkins CI` integration in GitLab. Thing is, [These are the options to configure in the Jenkins CI integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbMH4.png), and it doesn't seem like it allows to trigger it only when the Merge Request is for master or to pass any parameters.

Is it possible to configure it so that only if a Merge Request to master occurs it would trigger the Jenkins job with the source branch as a parameter? Is there another/better way of doing it?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

confing in your projects jenkins:
[image]

 config in your gitlab:

[image]

or orther my answer 
[image]

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I have done that and I do get an HTTP 200. However, I also need to get two parameters, source branch and target branch for the merge request. And have the Job execute only if the target branch = master. Is it possible to do? Thanks ahead!

Comment: Update: I just used the environment variable from that job and it worked! Thank you SO SO MUCH for the help and including the images, I really appreciate it! Solved.

Comment: Not at all, bro.